# Can't access gridview controls with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a DropDownList in a gridview like this :

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Application">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="headerApp" runat="server" Text="Application ↕️" CommandArgument="Application" CommandName="Sort" ></asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList  runat="server" CssClass="DDLApp" ID="DDListApp" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <%#Eval("Application") %>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

I would like to add searchable text to my DDList with a js component.

But when I try to add it, I can't reach my DDList.

I already tried :

```
$('#<%=gridview.FindControl("DDListApp").ClientID %>').customselect(); 
$('#<%=gridview.ClientID %>').find('span[id$="DDListApp"]').customselect();
```

Or even static client ID and CssClass but never succeed.

You need to know that the script work when i'm outside GridView

So, How can I access my value properly?

Comment: You are still not specifying in which row you want to look for the control: `gridview.Rows[i].FindControl("DDListApp")`

Comment: It's the header row so I try : 
`$('#<%=gridview.Rows[0].FindControl("DDListApp").ClientID %>').customselect();`
But still not working

**EDIT :** `$('#<%=gridview.HeaderRow.FindControl("DDListApp").ClientID %>').customselect();` didn't work too

Comment: Oh no my bad, `$('#<%=gridview.HeaderRow.FindControl("DDListApp").ClientID %>').customselect();` is fine. I just forget a CSS class to add in my DDList ^^'.
Thanks a lot @VDWWD